# programmatically configuration for spring boot micrometer with influxdb

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am facing some challenges while configuring `Spring Boot Micrometer` for my application. Micrometer documents says we can configure `influxdb uri, userName, password, db` etc through `application.yml` file which is working fine for my demo application but for production ready application we are using `docker-compose` and we are setting all our environment variable through `docker-compose`. Now I am facing challenges like -

1. How can I force micrometer to use `docker-compose` environment variable `influxdb uri`
2. For `influxdb` password, our application stores passwords in `AWS secret Manager`, how micrometer will access password from secret manager?
3. Can I configure all this micrometer properties programmatically (Spring Bean)? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to leverage AWS Secret Manager, but for point 1 and 3 I can offer some advice.

I'm not familiar with Influx specifically, but based on the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/influx/InfluxProperties.html) it uses `management.metrics.export.influx.username` to set the password.

1- To set a application property via an environment variable, set the equivalent using the typical 'SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE' format:

```sh
MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_INFLUX_USERNAME=myInfluxUser
```

Or if you already have an environment variable that you want to reference in you application.yml file you con reference in as a property:

```yaml
management.metrics.export.influx.username: ${INFLUX_USER}
```

3- To configure Micromerter/influx programatically create a bean on type `InfluxProperties`:

```java
@Bean
public InfluxProperties influxProperties() {
  return new InfluxProperties(); // Programatically set any properties here.
}
```